# python: extend dataframe by slightly changing one rowvalue

Tags: python, loops, duplicates, row

Given dataframe:

```
Client Product Price 
 1       A      1
 2       A      2
 1       B      5
```

Is there and efficient way to extend this dataframe by multiplying each row price with 0.9 and 1.1 while still keeping the original rows as well? The result should look like this.

```
Client Product Price 
  1       A      1
  1       A      1.1
  1       A      0.9
  2       A      2
  2       A      2.2
  2       A      1.8
  1       B      5
  1       B      5.5
  1       B      4.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate the data frame, modify the copies and concatenate:

```
factors = [1.,1.1,0.9]
dfs = [df.copy() for _ in range(3)]
for i, factor in enumerate(factors):
    dfs[i]['Price'] *= factor
new_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This might be rather slow for large data frames, though.